# how to load xml files from Exist database?

Tags: xml, database, exist-db

i've been trying to load xml files that I have saved in the exist database so i can view it on the web, but nothing works could anyone tell me how to do that please . thanks

this is the Xml document that im trying to get from the exist database .

```
    <usanavy>
<officer_rank>
<officers_titles>
<ensign>ENS</ensign>
<lieutenant_junior>LTJG</lieutenant_junior>
<lieutenant>LT</lieutenant>
<lieutenant_commander>LCDR</lieutenant_commander>
<commander>CDR</commander>
<captain>CAPT</captain>
<rear_admiral_lowerhalf>RDML</rear_admiral_lowerhalf>
<rear_admiral>RDM</rear_admiral>
<vice_admiral>VADM</vice_admiral>
<admiral>ADM</admiral>
<fleet_admiral>FADM</fleet_admiral>
</officers_titles>
<officers_pay_grade>
<ensign>0 to 1</ensign>
<lieutenant_junior>0 to 2</lieutenant_junior>
<lieutenant>0 to 3</lieutenant>
<lieutenant_commander>0 to 4</lieutenant_commander>
<commander>0 to 5</commander>
<captain>0 to 6</captain>
<rear_admiral_lowerhalf>0 to 7</rear_admiral_lowerhalf>
<rear_admiral>0 to 8</rear_admiral>
<vice_admiral>0 to 9</vice_admiral>
<admiral>0 to 10</admiral>
<fleet_admiral>special</fleet_admiral>
</officers_pay_grade>
</officer_rank>
<commissioned_warrant_officers>
<chief_warrant_officer_two>w-2</chief_warrant_officer_two>
<chief_warrant_officer_three>w-3</chief_warrant_officer_three>
<chief_warrant_officer_four>w-4</chief_warrant_officer_four>
<chief_warrant_officer_five>w-5</chief_warrant_officer_five>
</commissioned_warrant_officers>
<non_commissioned_warrant_officers>
<seaman_recruit>E-1</seaman_recruit>
<seaman_apprentice>E-2</seaman_apprentice>
<seaman>E-3</seaman>
<petty_officer_third_class>E-4</petty_officer_third_class>
<petty_officer_second_class>E-5</petty_officer_second_class>
<petty_officer_first_class>E-6</petty_officer_first_class>
<chief_petty_officer>E-7</chief_petty_officer>
<senior_chief_petty_officer>E-8</senior_chief_petty_officer>
<master_chief_petty_officer>E-8</master_chief_petty_officer>
<command_master_chief_petty_officer>E-9</command_master_chief_petty_officer>
<fleet_master_chief_petty_officer>E-9</fleet_master_chief_petty_officer>
<master_chief_petty_officer_of_navy>E-9</master_chief_petty_officer_of_navy>
</non_commissioned_warrant_officers>
<ships>
<uss_abraham type="aircraft carrier">carrier</uss_abraham>
<uss_alabama type="missle submarine">Ballistic missile submarine</uss_alabama>
<uss_alaska type="missle submarine">Ballistic missle submarine</uss_alaska>
<uss_warrior>mine counterneasures</uss_warrior>
<uss_virginia>attack submarine</uss_virginia>
<uss_wasap>assault ship</uss_wasap>
<uss_tortuga>dock lanfing ship</uss_tortuga>
</ships>
</usanavy>
```

Comment: Can you give us more info and maybe some code?

Comment: what is the database rec type? and what is the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml files can be seen directly via URL in browser.
e.x. http://localhost/exist/servlet/db/the-path-of-your-xml-file.xml

And if you want to use it in the page of your website, just use javascript with AJAX.